# How do I access the height of a tableView cell from within tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, tableview

I need to grab the height of a tableView cell from within the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

I set the height of the row in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` to return 200 for example. However in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`, when I do `NSLog(@"cell height: %f", cell.contentView.frame.size.height);` I don't get 200, I get the default cell height of 44.0. The size of the cell however is visually correct in the simulator. There must be a way to get the size that is specified in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` directly without me having to store it in a separate variable - no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just call within the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Here's an example:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   CGFloat cellHeight = [self tableView:self.tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is used by the table view only to determine the vertical position of each cell in the table view, the size of the scroll indicator and such things.

But in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you are responsible for creating a cell with the same height, either by setting the `frame` or by defining the cell with correct height in a NIB/Storyboard file.

These two methods are independent. There is no magic that cells are created with the height of 
`tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. If you create a larger cell, then this cell will just overlap with the next cell in the table view.

So you can call your own `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method (and I just see that @Larcus94 has suggested exactly this).

But if the height is the same for all cells in the table, a separate constant would be more effective.